# Android keyboard keypress not returning anything & keydown returning 229

Tags: javascript, android, forms, google-chrome, keycode

On my portfolio, I made a form that mocks the macOs iMessage interface. You can view the page here (and drop me a cool message that will be ending up straight into my MySQL database).

[https://perso-etudiant.u-pem.fr/~letien04/Portfolio/assets/imessage_form.php](https://perso-etudiant.u-pem.fr/%7Eletien04/Portfolio/assets/imessage_form.php)

However, I've got an issue with Android keyboard.

The principle of work of the form is the following :

When you fill an input and you press either tab or enter, the script detects the relevant keycode onkeypress or onkeydown (I temporarely enabled both, that's not definitive), then "remove" the input by adding a .screen-reader-text class (http://www.coolfields.co.uk/2016/05/text-for-screen-readers-only-updated/) onto it, which displays the next input that you can fill by following the instructions dynamically given above in the page.

My issue is the following. The page is working perfectly fine when a physical keyboard is in use on a desktop web browser. It starts getting shitty on mobile. Onkeypress (console.logged) isn't detecting anything and onkeydown only detect a 229 keyCode.

I've got an access to a console on Android using this app : https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.asfmapps.f12

In that way, the form is absolutely unusable on Android.

Here's the relevant code :

```html
<form method="POST" action="target.php" autocomplete="off">
        <input type="text" required class="messageInput" placeholder="Your first name, last name and company name" name="names" style="z-index:3" onkeydown="sending(event,this)" onkeypress="sending(event,this)">
        <input type="text" required class="messageInput" placeholder="Your email adress" name="email" style="z-index:2" onkeydown="sending(event,this)" onkeypress="sending(event,this)">
        <textarea name="message" required rows="1" class="messageInput" style="z-index:0" placeholder="Your message"></textarea>
        <input type="image" src="../images/send_button.png" border="0" alt="Submit" />
    </form>
```

```js
function sending(e,el){
        
        var code = (e.keyCode ? e.keyCode : e.which);

        console.log(code);

        /*⬇ code == 13 → Return/Enter & code == 9 → Tab ⬇*/
        if(code == 13 || code == 9) {
            let val = el.value;

            if(val != ''){

                if(el.name == "names"){
                    document.querySelector('main').innerHTML += `
                        <p class="message-sent">${val}</p>
                        <p class="message-received">Alright ${val}, nice to meet you ! Can I please ask you for your email address ? You can type it in the field below !</p>
                    `;
                } else if(el.name == "email"){
                    document.querySelector('main').innerHTML += `
                        <p class="message-sent">${val}</p>
                        <p class="message-received">Thanks ! I'll be using this email address to reach you once I've read your message ! Talking about message, what is it ? You can type it below as well as before.</p>
                    `;
                }

                el.classList.add('screen-reader-text');
            }
        }
    }
```

For any further investigations, you can find the full code here :
https://github.com/LoicE5/Portfolio/blob/main/assets/imessage_form.php
(it may be not fully updated but functional on desktop and the few modified code is written above).

Thanks a lot for any solution path you may guys find !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[keypress event](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/keypress_event) is no longer supported by browsers

> When using virtual/mobile keyboards, formally known as IME (Input-Method Editor), the W3C standard states that a KeyboardEvent’s e.keyCode should be 229 and e.key should be "Unidentified".

source: https://javascript.info/keyboard-events#mobile-keyboards

Comment: What's the alternative?